# Connection to a Teradata DB using LDAP and SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

```
**import pandas as pd 
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Teradata};'
                  'Server=XXXXXXX;'
                  'DBCNAME=DB_name;'
                  'AUTHENTICATION=LDAP;'
                  "UID=XXXXXXX;"
                  "PWD='XXXXXXX;"
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
 # Read the sql file
SQL_Query = pd.read_sql(''


Select *

FROM DB_name.table_name

'''
, conn)**
```

---

I'm getting the error below: I'm thinking my Parameters in pyodbc.connect are not correct.  Can anybody help?

OperationalError: ('08001', "[08001] [WSock32 DLL] 10065 WSA E HostUnreach: The Teradata server can't currently be reached over this network (10065) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Answer (score 1):

I got the following parms to work.

```
import pandas as pd 
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Teradata};'
                  'Server=server_name;'
                  'DBCNAME=dsn_NAME;'
                  'AUTHENTICATION=LDAP;'
                  'UID={USER_ID};'
                  "PWD={pw};"
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

SQL_Query = pd.read_sql('''

SELECT *

FROM DB_name.Table_name
'''
, conn)

SQL_output_pd = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query)
```